# How to pass data to next table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, segue, datasource

So I have a dictionary of stored keys with multiple values. I have two view controllers, both contain a table view and custom cells.

I have placed the keys in an array and assigned them to be the text of the cell's label in the first view controller. When transitioning to the next view controller I would like to pass down the values of the key that was pressed. So for example, in the first view controller if you selected a row that contained the first key in the dictionary, all of the values of the first key would be assigned to the cell label text's for the following view controller and so on. Is this possible, and if so what would be the best way to implement this?

Here is my code for the first view controller:

```
 import UIKit

var trainingDict = ["Ball Handling" : ["1 Ball Stationary Drills", "1 Ball Combo Moves", "2 Ball Stationary Drills", "2 Ball Combo Moves", "2 Ball Partner Drills", "Handle Hoop Drills"], "Shooting" : ["Form Shooting", "Spot Shooting", "Off The Dribble Shots", "Pull Up Jumpshots", "Catch & Shoots", "Free Throws", "Partner Shooting"], "Defense" : ["5 Star Drill", "Full Court Def. Slides", "1 v 1 Closeouts", "Gauntlet Drill", "Tennis Ball Reaction Drill", "Lane Slides"], "Advanced Drills" : ["D Man Series", "Iso Series", "Double Move Series", "Gauntlet Series", "John Wall Drill", "Floater Series"], "Vertimax Drills" : ["One Foot Jumps", "Box Jumps", "Resitance Slides", "Resistance Jumps", "Resistance Ball Handling", "Vertimax Sprints", "Slam Drill"], "Full Workouts" : ["Workout A", "Workout B", "Workout C", "Workout D", "Workuot E", "Workout F", "Workout G"], "BHB Products" : ["Handle Hoops", "Handle Cubes", "Strech Bands", "Advocare"]]
var gradient : CAGradientLayer!
var myIndex = 0


 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



@IBOutlet weak var tableView: TableView!

var trainingCategories = [String]()
var arrayForKey = [String]()
var selectedKey = String()




public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return trainingDict.count
}




public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bell" , for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row




    //cell details
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //gradient details
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    //details what the text label of cell displays
    var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
    trainingCategories.sort { return $0 < $1}
    cell.textLabel?.text = trainingCategories[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myIndex = indexPath.row
    selectedKey = trainingCategories[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        if let secondTableView = segue.destination as? DrillsViewController {

            //get array for selected key
            arrayForKey = trainingDict[selectedKey]!

            //pass to second table view
            secondTableView.arrayForKey2 = arrayForKey
            }
        }


    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
    trainingCategories.sort { return $0 < $1}
}
```

Here's code for the second view controller that the first controller segues to:

```
  import UIKit



 import UIKit



class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var arrayForKey2 = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: DrillsTableView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillLabel: UILabel!


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return arrayForKey2.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath) as! DrillsTableViewCell

    //clear background color needed in order to display gradient cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //gradient configuration
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)



    //attributes for watch/play button
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1

    //details for cell label display

    cell.drillTitle.text = "\(arrayForKey2[indexPath.row])"


    return cell
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

       }
```

Comment: (1) You aren't really explaining the relationship between those view controllers.  (2) You don't have a dictionary variable to receive the data from the first view controller.  (3) You don't tell the result when you try to send data from one view controller to another.

Comment: then how do I so with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest declaring 3 variables at the top of table view 1:

1. `var trainingCategories: [String]?` to hold your dict keys
2. `var arrayForKey: [String]?` to hold the appropriate array from the dictionary
3. `var selectedKey: String?` to hold the selected dict key

Also create a variable in table view 2 to hold the dict array which you will pass from table view 1. E.g. `var arrayForKey2: [String]?`

Put the following in something like your `viewDidLoad` method for table view 1 and remove from `CellForRowAt`. This stops it being called every time `CellForRowAt` is called on each reusable cell.

```
    trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
    trainingCategories?.sort { return $0 < $1}
```

In `didSelectRowAt`, get the selected dict key: `selectedKey = trainingCategories[indexPath.row]` before calling your `self.performSegue...` method.

Finally override your `prepareForSegue` method in table view 1 to pass the info to table view 2:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        secondTableView = segue.destination as! DrillsViewController
        //Get array for selected dictionary key
        arrayForKey = trainingDict[selectedKey]
        //Pass to second table view
        secondTableView.arrayForKey2 = arrayForKey
    }
}
```

In `cellForRowAt` in table view 2, you can then set cell labels as before. E.g. `cell.textLabel?.text = "\(arrayForKey2[indexPath.row])"`

UPDATE TO FIX:

- The following still exists in `cellForRowAt` of table view 1. Please remove.

  ```
  var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
  trainingCategories.sort { return $0 < $1}
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` of table view 1, remove the `var` before at the beginning of the following line.

`var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)`

Comment: when you mean place at top of table view do do you mean after or before the class declaration?

Comment: After the class declaration

Comment: when I run it I get an fatal index out of range error

Comment: Ah - in `numberOfRowsInSection` in table view 2, you will need to return arrayForKey2.count

Comment: Im still getting an out of index error at the `selectedKey = trainingCategories[indexPath.row]` part of the code in the first table view

Comment: Can you update your original question with your code for each view now?

Comment: the code is now up to date, still receiving the same error message as before

Comment: I have it working with the code you provided me. See my "update to fix" in my answer - you still need to remove from code from the `cellForRowAt` and updated what you have put in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Did you manage to get it fixed? If so, please could you accept my answer?